# Automatic login using jwt in Cookie in ASP.net MVC Core

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

My process flow is :

1. User logs into a Issuer Application (Username/Password)
2. Clicks a link of the Client Application that they want to goto
3. Issuer Application creates a jwt and stores it in a Cookie
4. Issuer Application does a Response.Redirect to Client Application
5. Client Application authenticates user using the jwt in the Cookie and creates the Principal and automatically logs in user.

Below is my Client Application setting from the Startup **ConfigureServices** method:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"));

            SigningCredentials SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidIssuer = "issuerapp",

                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidAudience = "clientapp",

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = SigningCredentials.Key,

                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };


            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "issuerapp";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                options.SaveToken = true;
            })
            .AddCookie(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:CookieName");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = authenticationSettings.AccessDeniedPath;
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    // Check if JWT needs refreshed 
                    OnValidatePrincipal = RefreshTokenMonitor.ValidateAsync,
                    OnSigningOut = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:LogoutPath"));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            });
```

In my Client Application I have all controllers decorated with [Authorize] attribute.

I need the Client Application automatically authenticating the user using the jwt. Which is not happening using the above mentioned configurations.
My AccessDeniedPath (Action Method) is not getting hit either.

The workaround that I have been using is to redirect user from the Issuer Applicaiton to a Login action in the Client Application where :

1. I read the jwt from the Cookie
2. Validate the jwt to get the Principal
3. Call httpContext.SignInAsync

How can I get the user logged in automatically using the jwt.

Any help / pointer are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default , the `AddJwtBearer` extension will get the token from request's Authorization header :

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

But you are pass the token in cookie , so you can find the token in cookie and set token in `OnMessageReceived` event in `AddJwtBearer` :

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents  {
    OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Token = ctx.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["jwt"];

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

Comment: Nan Yu, Thanks for your time. However, I went with a complete different approach that involved encrypting the cookie.
I followed the blog listed below:
https://amanagrawal.blog/2017/09/18/jwt-token-authentication-with-cookies-in-asp-net-core/