# Login via Postman on a .net core 3 app using Auth0

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, auth0, azure-logic-apps

I have a .net app with login setup via Auth0 (works fine with user interaction) but I want to login with a script with no user interaction, which isn't working. Basically I want to run a LogicApp or some script with hard coded user/pass at night that access a page inside my app.

I've tried Azure LogicApps and Postman with the same results. I try to access a page inside my app by passing user/password as basic auth. I get a few redirects and back to the signin page. Auth0 is no providing any logs, so I assume the authentication is not reaching Auth0.

Obs1: I had this setup that I'm sure was working about 6 months ago, just recently I realized that it had stopped working, could've been a change in Auth0 or due to migrating from .net core 2.1 to 3.

Obs2: I also started testing the login with a Bearer token, but there will be too many changes in the code that I want to leave it as a last resort.

**Snippet of Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>'''
{
options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

// Add authentication services
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
{
// Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
options.Authority = $"https://login.myapp.net";

// Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
options.ClientId = "*********";
options.ClientSecret = "****************;

//Set response type to code
options.ResponseType = "code";

// Configure the scope
options.Scope.Clear();
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("profile");
options.Scope.Add("email");

//Set the correct name claim type
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
NameClaimType = "name",
RoleClaimType = "https://schemas.myapp.net"
};

// Set the callback path
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

// Configure the Claims Issuer
options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";
```

**Postman result (3 redirects and a found - login page):**

```
GET https://myapp.net/  
302

GET https://myapp.net/Account%2FLogin
302

GET https://login.myapp.net/authorize?client_id=****************&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.myapp.net%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&code_challenge=***********&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=*****&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
302

GET https://login.myapp.net/login?state=***********&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.myapp.net%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&code_challenge=*********&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=*************&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
200
197ms 
▼
Request Headers
Authorization: Basic **********
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.22.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: **************
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: did=*********; auth0_compat=***********
Referer: https://login.myapp.net/authorize?client_id=***************&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.myapp.net%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&code_challenge=***********&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=******&state=*************&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
Connection: keep-alive
Response Headers
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 04:18:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ot-tracer-spanid: 6ed01af3e
ot-tracer-traceid: 3d5f35a407
ot-tracer-sampled: true
X-Auth0-RequestId: 655374d6432978
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 999
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1583900310
set-cookie: _csrf=eML8VgsIOn-ONcU0u3TeTx7U; Max-Age=864000; Path=/usernamepassword/login; HttpOnly; Secure
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
ETag: W/"a6e-Dn+oh0+jgssgYbnM4PE"
cache-control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-transform
Content-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
▼
Response Body
[sign in page]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to document :  [Implement the Resource Owner Password Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant)

After config your application in portal , you can directly send a post request to Auth0's token endpoint with correct parameters like grant_type/client_id/client_secret/username/password and scope, and token endpoint will return access token which could be used to access the protected resource :

```
var client = new RestClient("https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=password&username=user%40example.com&password=pwd&audience=YOUR_API_IDENTIFIER&scope=read%3Asample&client_id=%24%7Baccount.clientId%7D&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

You can test with Fiddler or Postman .

Comment: I've tried that, but for that to work I need to change my startup.cs class to accept Bearer token as authentication. That's plan B, because it will demand other changes deep in the application that I want to avoid. But I'm starting to think that that may be the only option.

Comment: In postman you acquire access token from Auth0 for accessing your web api . After getting token , you can send http request with authorzation header and add the token , Then on your web api side , you need to add bearer authentication schema to validation token and sign in user .

Comment: Is there another way to login with no user interaction, without the bearer token? As of now the app runs fine with interactive authentication and no setup for bearer token. From my understanding the token is being sent through the cookie under the rug. Could I set the cookie up in Postman maybe?

Comment: That depends on how you validate your token in web api .  Checking the token in request header or in cookie  , but your web api still need to have authentication  handler to validate token and sign in user .

Comment: You did help me. I made it work in Postman, I had to enable the interceptor feature that grabs the cookie from the browser and use it to authenticate. I'll have to figure out how to do that with Azure Logic Apps which is my end goal.

Comment: if the reply helps , please accept as answer which may help others who meet same problem

Comment: In addtion , you can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60612387/5751404) for how to get jwt token auhtenciation from cookie if using ,net core web api ,

Comment: Thanks, yes it did help. I tried to vote up as well, but I don't have the reputation.